# Error in Gaussian Process Implementation

Tags: python, gaussian-process

I have been trying to define a Gaussian Process from hand by simply writing down the required formulas and apply them to an toy example. Here is what my (noise-free), observed data looks like:

```
x_observed = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.2).reshape(-1, 1)
y_observed = np.sin(x_train) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax.scatter(x_train, y)
```

[image]

Moreover, I used the exponential quadratic kernel function:

```
def kernel_func(X1, X2, l=1.0, sigma=1.0):
    
    sqdist = np.sum(X1**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(X2**2, 1) - 2 * np.dot(X1, X2.T)
    return sigma**2 * np.exp(-0.5 / l**2 * sqdist)
```

and defined the gaussian process:

```
def gp(x_observed, y_observed, x_new):
    
    k = kernel_func(x_observed, x_observed)
    K_star_star = kernel_func(x_new, x_new)
    K_star = kernel_func(x_observed, x_new)
    K_inv = np.linalg.inv(k)
    mu = K_star.T @ K_inv @ y_observed
    sigma = K_star_star - K_star.T @ K_inv @ K_star

    return mu, sigma
```

Creating new data, which I want a prediction for:

```
X_new = np.array([-3.5, -3, -2, -1, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

I can get the mean value for each $x_i$ in X_new, by calling the gaussian process function:

```
mu_s, cov_s = gp(x_observed, y_observed, X_new)
```

Now, I did expect that the point prediction, that is the mean, for some of the $x_i$ in `X_new` are equal to some values in `y_observed`, since we already know the target value, i.e. the values were already observed. However, looking at the observed y values and `mu_s` :

```
for i, x in  enumerate(X_new):
    print(f'target function {np.sin(x)}, prediction {mu_s[i]}')

target function [0.35078323], prediction [-6.27205575]
target function [-0.14112001], prediction [-1.03358472]
target function [-0.90929743], prediction [2.2573257]
target function [-0.84147098], prediction [3.20067827]
target function [0.84147098], prediction [-7.19285408]
```

I either have a missunderstanding of Gaussian Processes or an error in my code, but I could not find any bugs or similar

Comment: aren't you missing a transpose in the equation for mu ? (`K_star.T` instead of `K_star`)

Comment: I think this depends on the transpose used in the kernel function. I could also add the transpose, like you suggest, but then I have to adjust how I pass the input of the kernel function. The result should be the same.I will adjust it in the code though to avoid confusion.

Comment: Right. Anyway your understanding is correct so this must be a small bug somewhere. I would suggest testing the code with fewer observations and plotting the results, this might give you a hint about where things go wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the ill conditioning of your kernel matrix. These are the singular values of your kernel matrix k:

[image]

As you can see, many of them are numerically zero. This leads to nonsense when you compute np.linalg.inv.

You have two options. The most common is to simply add a scaled identity matrix to your kernel matrix with some small scaling value, like $10^{-6}$:

```
K_inv = np.linalg.inv(k + 1e-6 * np.eye(k.shape[0]))
```

This leads to correct predictions:

[image]

Another option is to notice that each time you explicitly compute a matrix inverse, Householder rolls around in his grave. We can allow him to rest easier by avoiding explicit inverse computation, and instead computing linear system solves. Like so:

```
def gp(x_observed, y_observed, x_new):

    k = kernel_func(x_observed, x_observed)
    K_star_star = kernel_func(x_new, x_new)
    K_star = kernel_func(x_observed, x_new)
    mu = K_star.T @ np.linalg.solve(k, y_observed)
    sigma = K_star_star - K_star.T @ np.linalg.solve(k, K_star)

    return mu, sigma
```

This also leads to good predictions:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I'm surprised numpy does not issue a warning when trying to inverse close to singular matrices

Comment: you saved my weekend, ty!

Comment: @J.Delaney - the issue is that "close" is in the eye of the beholder. Any value you picked would simultaneously get some people annoyed at nuisance warnings and others thinking they had a (nonexistent) safety net because they didn't get warnings.

Answer (score 4):

@John Madden gave a good answer pointing to the root cause of the problem, but adding to it, you should not invert that matrix directly in the first place. Matrix inversion is generally [inefficient](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/12/09/matrix-inversion/) and [not recommended](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) for all kinds of applications. This also applies to Gaussian processes. An efficient algorithm is given by [Rasmussen (2006)](http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) as Algorithm 2.1 on p 19:

$$\begin{align}
L &= \operatorname{cholesky}(K + \sigma^2 I) \\
\alpha &= L^\top \backslash (L \backslash y) \\
\mu &= K_{*}^\top \alpha \\
v &= L \backslash K_{*} \\
\Sigma^2 &= K_{**} - v^\top v \\
\end{align}$$

where $K = k(X, X)$, $K_{*} = k(X, X_*)$ and $K_{**} = k(X_*, X_*)$.

Comment: may be worth emphasizing that these are not any linear system solves that youre invoking, but lower diagonal ones which have complexity only quadratic in matrix dimension. BTW: do you think this approach is superior to the direct linear system solves I recommend? I've never actually compared the two, I could see it going either way... but anyways yes it's true this is the most popular approach, especially because determinant calculation is linear time once you've done a cholesky decomposition (in case you want to do marginal MLE).